# Check if the given string exists in array

Tags: c#, arrays

Trying to check if `Grapes` exists in `varieties`, but below code does not satisfy if condition, even though grapes exists in the array.

```
public enum Type
{   
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Grapes  
}


private Type[] varieties = default!;
if (varieties.Any(e => e.Equals("Grapes")))
{
    //Perform some operation
}
```

Whereas below satisfies if condition as expected, but I do not want to hard code as `varieties[0]`.

```
if (varieties[0].ToString() == "Grapes")
{
    //Perform some operation

}
```

May I know the correct condition for checking this. Thank you.

Comment: `varieties.Any(e => e == Type.Grapes)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An enum is not a string, so that doesn't return `true`.

```
varieties.Any(e => e.Equals("Grapes"))
```

You want:

```
if (varieties.Any(e => e == Type.Grapes))
{
    //Perform some operation

}
```

Sidenote: an enum name `Type` is not a good idea, since it conflicts with `System.Type`.

Comment: or you can also use the `Equals()` method like so: `Any(e => e.Equals(Type.Grapes))`

Answer (score 3):

As I can see from `default!`

```
 // Assign default value which is null
 // And do not show any warning for this (! - null forgiving)
 private Type[] varieties = default!;
```

`null` is a *possible option* in your case (a better practice is to use empty array):

```
 private Type[] varieties = Array.Empty<Type>();
```

If you want to *keep* `null` you have to use `?.`:

```
 // Note, that varieties contains items of type "Type"
 // So, we compare "Type", not "String"
 if (varieties?.Any(item => item == Type.Grapes) ?? false)
 {
 ...
 }
```

If you are ready to change `default!` into `Array.Empty<Type>()` then we can get rid of `null` check:

```
 if (varieties.Any(item => item == Type.Grapes))
 {
 ...
 }
```

Comment: Init to an empty array is definitely recommended, as you can just check if that array is empty. vs now having to include a lot more code just to handle the nullability of the field. I believe that `Array.Empty<T>()` also follows the singleton pattern, so its not as if nullability is going to yield any significant boost to efficiency whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

Checking if a string exists in an array is very easy with LINQ. Use the following code to check if a string exists in an array.

```
class Program
    {
        
        //method to check if the test string exists in the array
        static bool DoesItExist(string fruit, string[] fruits)
        {
            //initialize the return type to false
            var exists = false;
            //check if the item exists in the array with LINQ
            exists = fruits.Any(x => x== fruit);
            return exists;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //define your array
            string[] fruits = new string[] { "Grapes", "Mangoes", "Pineapples" };
            Console.WriteLine(DoesItExist("Grapes", fruits));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check if your value exist in the `enum` array is to use the 
`Array.Exists(array, conditionCheck)`

```
if (Array.Exists(varieties, v => v.Equals(Type.Grapes)))
{
    ...
}
```